# Perl one liner to simulate awk script

Tags: perl, awk, range

I'm new to both `awk` and `perl`, so please bear with me. 
I have the following `awk` script:

```
awk '/regex1/{p = 0;} /regex2/{p = 1;} p'
```

What this basically does is print all lines staring from line matching with regex2 until a line matching with regex1 is found.

Example:

```
 regex1
 regex2
 line 1
 line 2
 regex1
 regex2
 regex1
```

Output:

```
 regex2
 line 1
 line 2
 regex2
```

Is it possible to simulate this using a `perl` one-liner? I know I can do it with a script saved in a file.

Edit:

A practical example:

> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,827 [INFO] 123456 (Blah : Blah1) Service-name:: Single line content
>
> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,828 [INFO] 567890 (Blah : Blah1) Service-name:: Content( May span multiple lines)
>
> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,829 [INFO] 123456 (Blah : Blah2)
>   Service-name: Multiple line content. Printing Object[ ID1=fac-adasd 
>   ID2=123231
>   ID3=123108  Status=Unknown
>   Code=530007   Dest=CA
>   ]
>
> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,830 [INFO] 123456 (Blah : Blah1) Service-name:: Single line content
>
> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,831 [INFO] 567890 (Blah : Blah2) Service-name:: Content( May span multiple lines)

Given the search key 123456 I want to extract the following:

> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,827 [INFO] 123456 (Blah : Blah1) Service-name:: Single line content
>
> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,829 [INFO] 123456 (Blah : Blah2)
>   Service-name: Multiple line content. Printing Object[ ID1=fac-adasd 
>   ID2=123231
>   ID3=123108  Status=Unknown
>   Code=530007   Dest=CA
>   ]
>
> 24 May 2017 17:00:06,830 [INFO] 123456 (Blah : Blah1) Service-name:: Single line content

The following awk script does the job:
`awk '/[0-9]{2}\s\w+\s[0-9]{4}/{n = 0} /123456/ {n =1}n' file`

Comment: U know there is a progamm awk2perl which you could try?

Comment: for awk, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38972737/4082052 for better ways... if you know how to write perl script, see https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/perl/3696/perl-one-liners#t=201706141257567028325 and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches .. you'll want to use http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print if (/regex2/ .. /regex1/) =~ /^\d+$/'
```

This is slightly crazy, but here's how it works:

- `-n` adds an implicit loop over the input lines
- the current line is in `$_`
- the two bare regex matches (`/regex2/`, `/regex1`/) implicitly test against `$_`
- we use `..` in scalar context, which turns it into a stateful flip-flop operator

  By that I mean: `X .. Y` starts out in the "false" state. In the "false" state it only evaluates `X`. If `X` returns a false value, it remains in the "false" state (and returns false itself). Once `X` returns a true value, it moves into the "true" state and returns true.

  In the "true" state it only evaluates `Y`. If `Y` returns false, it remains in the "true" state (and returns true itself). Once `Y` returns a true value, it moves into the "false" state but it still returns true.
- had we just used `print if /regex2/ .. /regex1/`, it would have printed all the terminating `regex1` lines, too
- a close reading of [Range Operators in `perldoc perlop`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Range-Operators) reveals that you can distinguish the end points of the range
- the "true" value returned by `..` is actually a sequence number starting from `1`, so the start of a range can be identified by checking for `1`
- when the end of the range is reached (i.e. we're about to move from the "true" state to the "false" state again), the return value gets a `"E0"` tacked on to the end

  Adding `"E0"` to an integer doesn't affect its numeric value. Perl implicitly converts strings to numbers when needed, and something like `"5E0"` is just scientific notation (meaning `5 * 10**0`, which is `5 * 1`, which is `5`).
- the "false" value returned by `..` is the empty string, `""`

We check that the result of `..` matches the regex `/^\d+$/`, i.e. is all digits. This excludes the empty string (because we require at least one digit to match), so we don't print lines outside of the range. It also excludes the last line in our range, because `E` is not a digit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That is crazy indeed. I actually gave a very general example in the question, for which your code works. I also need to print the cases where regex1 and regex2 are on the same line(giving priority to regex2). But I believe I can do that on my own, thanks to your explanation.

Comment: @AkhilAvinash That sounds like it can be done with something like `my $p = /regex2/ .. /regex1/; print if $p && ($p == 1 || $p !~ /E/);`

Comment: No, that didn't do the job. When we have something line `regex1 regex2` It only prints that line but not the lines after, as the value of $p is somehow set to 1E0 inside the line itself. I believe that each $_ is matched with both /regex2/ and /regex1/, and hence the range ends inside the line itself. Let me know if there's a way around this.

Comment: @AkhilAvinash Oh! If I understand you correctly, that's just `...` instead of `..`.

Comment: I'm sorry this is becoming such a mess. But  there's another problem. When 
we have :
`regex1 regex2`\n
`multiple lines`  \n
`regex1 regex2`

The script doesn't print the last line. The above given practical example is what I'm testing on. My script is `perl -ne 'my $p = (/123456/.../[0-9]+ \w+ [0-9]{4}/); print if $p && ($p == 1 || $p !~ /E/);'  file`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if awk prints both the start and end of the range, but Perl does:

```
perl -ne 'if(/regex2/ ... /regex1/){print}' file
```

Edit: Awk (at least Gnu awk) also has a range operator, so this could have been done more simply as:

```
awk '/regex2/,/regex1/' file
```

Comment: I actually need the script to print only the start and the lines in between, excluding the end of the range. The awk script does exactly that. Is there a way to modify your perl one-liner to do the same?